# trouble with javascript measurement conversion function. "If ... else if... else"

Tags: javascript, function

I have the following function, which is supposed to get a number from an array declared elsewhere in the function this is nested in, look at the corresponding string in a string array, and apply a conversion factor to the number, and write the output to a different array. I'm using a canvas, so I wrote canvas code to output there for debugging, but I'm only ever getting the "else" statement at the end. The function should be called every time that the user updates the information in the page, and that is working correctly for other functions. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

```
function arrayFinalizer()
{
var itemSelector = document.getElementById("itemSelector");
var i = itemSelector.value - 1;

if (arrayInput[i] == "Ounces")
{
    arrayFinal[i] = Math.ceil(arrayOut[i] / 16);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillText("Ounces", 0, 20);
    return arrayFinal[i];
}
else if (arrayInput[i] == "Pounds")
{
    arrayFinal[i] = Math.ceil(arrayOut[i]);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillText("Pounds", 0, 20);
    return arrayFinal[i];
}
else if (arrayInput[i] == "Grams")
{
    arrayFinal[i] = Math.ceil(arrayOut[i] / 453.592);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillText("Grams", 0, 20);
    return arrayFinal[i];
}
else if (arrayInput[i] == "Kilograms")
{
    arrayFinal[i] = Math.ceil(arrayOut[i] * 2.20462);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillText("Kilograms", 0, 20);
    return arrayFinal[i];
}
else
{
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillText("mathEngine error", 0, 20);
    return;
}
};
```

Notes:

I know that arrayInput is correctly writing, and that the only values it can receive are "Ounces" "Pounds" "Grams" and "Kilograms" because I have used the         array.ToString() method both before and after this point in the program to check it's values.

I also know that arrayOut has numeric values for the above-mentioned reason. I know that I am successfully calling this function because I am getting the else fillText output, and it is overwriting another debug statement further up stream.

I have tried both the "==" and "===" operators for my if statements, and there is no difference.

Finally, I am not receiving any error messages in my console.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML as well?  Also, you should consider using switch/case statements

Comment: Please do a `console.log(arrayInput, i)` for us in the third line of your function and post the result

Comment: $5 says `itemSelector.value` is not returning a value that can be coerced to an integer. You should check it in the debugger or dump the value to the console with `console.log(itemSelector.value)`.

Comment: Use a switch statement instead of multiple if...else statements

Comment: Okay. Bergi, those are as follows:
blastfrag.js:158 [1: "ounces", NaN: undefined] 1
Ghazgkull, itemSelector.value == the value of the drop down selected (1, 2, 3... and so-on).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CAlbano/s4mzssm1/ has the html. The javascript is an old build from when I was trying to solve a different bug, and doesn't include this or a few other portions of the script. I can post more if it's needed though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please put this on line no. 5th and tell us the console log so that we can easily resolve it.

```
console.log(i);
console.log(arrayInput);
```

If you are confident with i being as integer and arrayInput with mentioned possible values, you can apply this for each of if condition and try again:

```
if (arrayInput[i].toLowerCase().trim() == "ounces")
else if (arrayInput[i].toLowerCase().trim() == "pounds")
```

Comment: That solves it. I don't know whether to be more embarrassed that all my serious problems are typing errors or that I don't catch them in hours of sifting through my code. Hopefully it will come with experience. Thanks!

Comment: Cool..It will come with experience. Could you please upvote for this answer so that I can earn some points to add comments on others post.

Comment: It won't allow me to yet. I need a little more reputation. I will as soon as I am able to though. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging `arrayInput[i]` in the `else` clause to make sure you're getting the values you expect? You mentioned debug statements, so 
please update us with your output so that it's easier for us to see what's going on.

Also, your code could have use some cleanup.

Instead of using chained `else if` statements, consider using a `switch` statement:

```
switch (arrayInput[i]) {
    case "Ounces":
        // Logic here
    break;
    // Everything else
    default:
        // Catch-all (final `else` clause)
        // No break required

}
```

You should also pass in `arrayInput` and `i` as a parameter when you call the `arrayFinalizer` so you could debug it in the console easier.

```
function arrayFinalizer(arrayInput, i) { ... }
```

Console:

```
arrayFinalizer(["Ounces"], 0) -> ???
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to make it switch, but I'm rather inexperienced and have yet to successfully implement switches. I've tried a few times (here included) and got frustrated and gone back to what I know how to work. Knowing that the problem was a typo in the strings I was comparing, I'll try again though.